# Creating an outset mask around svg shape

Tags: svg, mask, svg-filters

In an art-project I'm drawing svg-shapes all over the canvas, so that they can overlap at times:
[image]

In these cases I want the result to look something like this:

[image]

I think I would have to create some kind of shape surounding the foreground shape, but I have no clue how I would be able to do that dynamically. Is there even a way to do this? From some other questions I got the hint, there might be a possibility using filters. I would be happy to do it this way if there is no other, but I also heared these filters are quite resource intensive, what would be a problem, since I'm animating quite a bit here.

Hope you can help me.
Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If those are strokes with a stroke but no fill you can do the following: you use every path twice with a different stroke width

```css
svg{background:#ccc; width:300px;}
```

```html
<svg viewBox = "0 0 100 100">
  <defs>
    <path id="test" d="M10,75Q33,75 50,50 T90,25" fill="none" />
  </defs>
    <use xlink:href="#test" style="stroke:#fff;stroke-width:10; stroke-linecap: round" />
    <use xlink:href="#test" style="stroke:#000;stroke-width:3; stroke-linecap: round" />
```

Comment: Oh, thank you :) I can't believe I didn't have that Idea myself ^^

Comment: That would also work with outlines: white stroke for the background, black fill for the foreground. (SVG 2 [paint-order](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/paint-order) isn't widely enough implemented yet to use only one shape.)